# Write a 2D matrix with big real numbers to a file

Tags: fortran

I am trying to write a 2D matrix with big real numbers to file in the 2D matrix form, matrix looks as shown in the following image, also, the matrix can be download from here ([link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_2n16ZmkTFDmep2DoFXiBowqAJ2nlLHA)), I am using the following code, for writing to file,

```
 write(6,*) mat_var_name
  do i=1,nrows
    write(6, '(*(1000F14.7))')real(mat_var(i,:ncols))               
  enddo
```

[image]

The above code works fine, when writing matrices with small values, as showing in the following image, but it is not working when writing big real numbers,

[image]

Could you suggest a solution to write 2D matrices with big real numbers to an external file,

Edit after @ian-bush and @vladimir-f comments,

Thanks for your support, `write(6, '(*(F30.7))')real(mat_var(i,:ncols))`  is working, I am getting the desired result as follows,
[image]

Comment: Please explain the problem. What is wrong with your picture? Which exact number is wrong? How wrong? What should be there instead?

Comment: Be aware that unit `6` is most often pre-connected to standard output.

Comment: Is it full of stars? Do you want to keep strict columns in the output? Would a e or g edit descriptor (i.e. the thing in the format) instead of an f be acceptable?

Comment: Are the matrices you've shown definitely printed using the `f14.7` descriptor? Neither matrix looks like it's formatted in that way.

Comment: @VladimirF, thanks for asking, I have updated the pictures with snapshots taken from output files. Wrong, is big numbers are not printing, fortran is printing only stars and zeros, I want the acutal numbers as shown in the second image

Comment: @The_Learner could you edit it again to show both the numbers you want to output, and the output you are actually getting

Comment: You need to provide enough characters so that the format you request can fit. `F14.7` only provides 14 characters, 1 is the decimal point and 7 are the decimal places. Therefore it only allows 6 decimals in front of the decimal point. You need to either 1. provide more characters, e.g. F20.7 or just use the exponential (scientific) notation. Please see the links I gave you. With very large numbers you should be better off with the exponential format (that means the E G EN ES descriptors). Remember that you likely also need to print a blank between your columns (1X or TR1).

Comment: The answer in the first link suggests `E16.8`. Try it. Or try `G16.8`. Or if you do not care about columns you can try `G0.8`.

Comment: @VladimirF @ian-bush, Thanks for your support, `write(6, '(*(F30.7))')real(mat_var(i,:ncols)) ` is working, I am getting the desired result as edited in the answer, is there any limit to `w` in `Fw.d`, because, when use `F140.20`, The space between the columns is very high.

Comment: I am not aware of such limit but be aware that floating point numbers in computers are not valid for 140 decimal digits. More like 15 for double precision and less for single precision. Think about using the exponential format.

Comment: @VladimirF, thank you very much, I will use that